# AndroidPdfViewer - Can not open PDF document from Assets folder

Tags: java, android, file, pdf, assets

I've been working with [this PDF library](https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidPdfViewer), trying to get the path to where the PDF file resides, but I keep getting an error. What am I missing here?

[image]

Checking my Android Device Monitor, i can see my db in that database folder which also reside in the assets folder but i can't find all the pdf files? please where are they? check the image below

[image]

Thanks friends, it was my mistake, i just discovered that i need to read the file from assets into file directory before opening it. Is working right now using the code below

`
    private void CopyReadAssets(String fileName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

```
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), fileName);

    try
    {
        in = assetManager.open(fileName);
        out = this.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        Utility.copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File dir_file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());

    //<-- Get FileType
    String mimeType = Utility.getFileMineType(dir_file);

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType); //"file://" + getFilesDir() + "/abc.pdf"),"application/pdf"
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    if(mimeType.equals("application/pdf")){

        Log.e(TAG, Uri.fromFile(file).toString()+" -- "+dir_file);

        //mPDFView = new StudentPdfViewer();
        // mPDFView.display("Symfony.pdf", false);

        //handle it as activity
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, PdfViewer.class);
        intent1.putExtra(Config.COURSE_FILE, fileName);
        //intent1.putExtra(SqliteDb.COURSE_NAME,  listCategory.get(0).getCategory_name());
        //intent1.putExtras(mBundle);
        startActivity(intent1);

    }else{

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load selected Course Material, Please check the Study Studio installation guide to install the required dependency softwares", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

There is no "assets folder" on the device, and there is no "path to where the PDF file reside" on the device.

The contents of the `assets/` folder(s) in your app's project are stored inside the APK. You can access assets via an `AssetManager`, and you get one of those by calling `getAssets()` on any handy `Context`, such as an `Activity`.

Comment: The problem here is that i need a uri path to the file reside in assets folder when the program is running but the application was unable to find any file in that path, i check my Android Device Monitor to see if there's any of the file but no file in that directory. this is what i used `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ "sample.pdf" i'm missing anything here?